# $X\le Y$ but $V(X\mid Y)>V(Y\mid Y)$

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, variance

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are non negative random variables. Is it possible that $X\le Y$ almost surely, but $V(X\mid \sigma(Z))+E(X\mid \sigma(Z))>V(Y\mid \sigma(Z))+E(Y\mid \sigma(Z))$ almost surely?
I think yes, but I could not find an example. Could someone provide one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Z=1$, $X$ is Bernoulli with probability $p \in (0,1)$ and $Y=1$.

Comment: yes ofc, sorry i misstated the question. I want $E(X\mid Z)+Var(X\mid Z)>E(Y\mid Z)+Var(Y\mid Z)$

Comment: Well, this also works with the following small change: instead of X, Y, Z, consider Z'=Z, X'=nX, Y'=nY with p=1/2 and n > 1...

Comment: what do you mean with $Z=Z'$?

Comment: I just meant Z=1, X=n with probability 1/2, 0 with probability 1/2, Y=n, with n>1.